# Code Coverage and Unit Testing of Python Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have already visited [Preferred Python unit-testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191673/preferred-python-unit-testing-framework). I am not just looking at Python Unit Testing Framework, but also code coverage with respect to unit tests. So far I have only come across [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/coverage.html). Is there any better option?

An interesting option for me is to integrate [cpython](http://www.python.org/), unit testing of Python code and code coverage of Python code with Visual Studio 2008 through plugins (something similar to [IronPython Studio](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPythonStudio)). What can be done to achieve this? I look forward to suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you could define "better".  What do you want to do that coverage.py doesn't do?  How do you need it to be better?

Comment: I was referring to Limitations (section 4 of http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/rees-coverage.html) when I mentioned "better".

Comment: I'd add that integration of coverage.py with IDEs (Eclipse, in my particular case) would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyDev seems to allow code coverage from within Eclipse.

I've yet to find how to integrate that with my own (rather complex) build process, so I use Ned Batchelder's coverage.py at the command line.

Comment: I suggest a visit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262777/how-to-get-unit-test-coverage-results-in-eclipse-pydev

Answer (score 5):

We use this [Django coverage integration](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/705/), but instead of using the default coverage.py reporting, we generate some simple HTML: 
[Colorize Python source using the built-in tokenizer](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52298/).

Answer (score 2):

There is also [figleaf](http://darcs.idyll.org/~t/projects/figleaf/doc/) which I think is based on Ned Batchelder's coverage.py. We use [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/) as the driver for the testing. It all works pretty well. We write our unit tests using the built-in unittest and doctest modules.

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans' new Python support has tightly integrated code coverage support - [more info here](http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/netbeans_screenshot_of_the_week6).

Answer (score 1):

If you want interactive code coverage, where you can see your coverage stats change in real time, take a look at [Python Coverage Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/python/coverage/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Testoob](http://code.google.com/p/testoob/) has a neat "`--coverage`" command-line option to generate a coverage report.

Comment: Orip, which branch of Testoob has the --coverage option?  I've 1.13 release currently installed, but it doesn't seem to have that option there.

Cheers
H

Comment: Ah, ignore that.  Wasn't reading the docs correctly.

For other interested parties, use the following syntax:

testoob --coverage=normal test_file.py

types of coverage are silent, slim, normal, massive, or xml

Comment: @howard: glad you like it :) There's a new version with some coverage improvements coming out soon.