# How to get unit test coverage results in Eclipse + Pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, code-coverage, pydev

I know Eclipse + PyDev has an option `Run As` => `3 Python Coverage`. But all it reports is:

> Ran 6 tests in 0.001s
>
> OK

And it says nothing about code coverage. How to get a code coverage report in Pydev?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Run a file with "Python Coverage"
- Window > Show View > Code Coverage Results View
- Select the directory in which the executed file is
- Double-click on the executed file in the file list
- Statistics are now at the right, not executed lines are marked red in the code view

Actually this is a really nice feature, didn't know about it before :)

Comment: Did not work for me, when I select the directory with the python file it's not listed in the coverage view.

Comment: You might as well have to `pip3 install pytest-cov` to make this work .

Answer (score 8):

Note that in pydev 2.0, the coverage support changed, now, you should first open the coverage view and select the 'enable code coverage for new launches'... after that, any launch you do (regular or unit-test) will have coverage information being gathered (and the results inspection also became a bit more intuitive).

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps http://www.machine-envy.com/blog/2006/07/29/automated-python-testing-with-nose-and-eclipse/

It uses nosetests with the `–with-coverage` option.

Comment: it seems that everyone in SO supports nose ;)