# PyDev: Code Coverage Tool displays always 0%

Tags: python, eclipse, code-coverage, pydev

I am using the plugin "PyDev" for Eclipse. This puligun includes a Code-Coverage Tool.
I get no results when I execute my python file via right click-> "Run as" -> "Python Code Coverage".

The "Exec"-Column and "Cover"-Column displays always '0'. Although when I click "Refresh coverage information".

Comment: Did you check out the [step-by-step tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262777/how-to-get-unit-test-coverage-results-in-eclipse-pydev/2262839#2262839) for using the coverage tool?

Comment: Do you have the coverage module installed?