# How to check that all functions have a test case?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a standard method to check if all functions of all files that are included in a test have a testcase? So if I have `script_1.py`, `script_2.py` and `script_3.py` with corresponding `test_script_1.py`, `test_script_2.py` and `test_script_3.py`, how can I check that every function in `script_x.py` gets called at least ones by the test scripts?

I wrote the test functions in the format `def test<Name_of_function>_<test_condition>` so for example the function `def sum(a, b)` has test functions `def testSum_valid_input` and `def testSum_invalid_input`, so I could write a script that gets all the function names from the test scripts and compare that to the functions in the tested scripts, but I am hoping that there is already an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is probably to use a coverage tool. It will tell you how much of your code is called at least one time by a test.

Comment: Thanks, now that I know it's called coverage I found the python script http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262777/how-to-get-unit-test-coverage-results-in-eclipse-pydev for eclipse

Comment: @Niek: Now you will get high quality code ^^ You can also use pylint (excellent tool) I think it can do code coverage